# Rosparam load without overriding

Tags: ros, rosparam, load

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to load a .yaml file without overriding parameters? I have two independent .launch files that depend on the same .yaml file storing the configuration of the package, but one section of the package (corresponding to a one .launch file) might change the parameters (without dumping into the .yaml file), and the other section needs to get the newest parameters, which in this case would be those in the parameter server, not in the .yaml file.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173575/rosparam-load-without-overriding/) by [crpizarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9346/crpizarr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2014-06-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe you can do this with rosparam.

Instead, you should architect your launch files so that this isn't a problem. Perhaps you could create a third launch file just for loading parameters at startup?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1